# Javascript, Best way to append large very large table to DOM

Tags: javascript, append, innerhtml

I am using JSON and PHP to return a very large table 10,000+ records.

The problem I am having is I use innerHTML to append that table to the DOM but this sometimes takes 15 seconds or more and crashes the browser.  Is there any solution to optimize this somehow?  The table is already pre-built into one string in PHP, so all I have to do is append it.

Comment: Nothing you can do, you can try rendering a lazy HTML table but that requires a lot of work.

Comment: As a further aside you should never be sending HTML to the client over ajax. You should send JSON and have the client build the table.

Comment: The table is coming from MySQL so there is no way I can think of to build it on the client.  Why is sending HTML over ajax bad?

Comment: The size of the data being sent can be much larger if it is in HTML than JSON.  Also, having it send HTML kind of limits you what you can do with the data.  If sending JSON, you could do much more than just display it as a table.

Comment: @Ray because HTML is supposed to be loaded by browsers to render into a _NEW_ document. When you already have a document you use DOM methods and data to create new elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach would probably be to use a smaller table with pagination (I'm not sure anybody really wants to scroll through 10k+ rows).

Another approach, if you're insistent on having such a large table, might be to break up the HTML into chunks of rows (or even grouped with `<tbody>` elements) and then use a timer to append them to a table in the DOM.

Comment: I guess I could break up the table into like 10 smaller parts in PHP and then set a timer in javascript to build those parts in intervals.  I thought that there would be an easier way though.

Comment: @Ray: That website with that configuration caused 5MB+ to be downloaded. It's probably not what you want. I honestly think you should really think of some other approach perhaps.

Comment: Alright thanks for the suggestions.  How can you tell how much is being downloaded?  I'm not so good on the HTML/Javascript side.  I have firebug installed but not really sure of its full capabilities.

Comment: @Ray: Google Chrome has a task manager which shows network usage for each tab/process.